# NumberFormatException when parsing the output of a BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, numberformatexception

I'm learning to use BufferedReader I've tried with only 1 variable (a) and I received a normal answer. But I get an error when I put more than two variables (a and b).

```
import java.io.*;

public class Frequency {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
  {
    // these are the variables that make up the equation (y)
    double x , y, i, z, w, a, b, c;
    final double t;
    InputStreamReader isr =new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);
    System.out.println(" Enter the value of a and b to solve for y ");

    String s1 ;
    s1=br.readLine();
    String s2 ;
    s2=br.readLine();

    // variables of the equation
    a =Double.parseDouble(s1);
    b= Double.parseDouble(s2);
    t= 0.002 * Math.pow(10,-2);

    // I separated the equation into different parts
    i= 2*3.14* Math.pow(10, 6) * t ;
    x = Math.sin(i);
    z= 2 * 3.14 *5 * Math.pow(10, 5);
    w= Math.cos(z);
    c= Math.exp(-a*t);

    // equation of y
    y= Math.abs(x+w)/c+ 50*b ;
    System.out.println(" The output of y is " + y);
  }
}
```

Output 
2 3

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2 3"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at homeworkcsc201.Frequency.main(Frequency.java:26)
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the text of the variables by doing `s1=br.readLine();` and `s2=br.readLine();`, which implies that each one appears on a separate line. However the input you pass in is `2 3`, which is all on one line.

The exception happens because you attempt to parse each line as a single number: `a = Double.parseDouble(s1);` and `b = Double.parseDouble(s2);`. `parseDouble` requires the *entire* string to represent a single number, but you are passing in `"2 3"` as `s1`, which is exactly what the error message is telling you.

The correct thing would be to type <kbd>2</kbd>, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>3</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. Basically, put each number on a separate line as your program expects.

Answer (score 1):

> `at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)`

The stack-trace shows that the failure is in the method `parseDouble`, which expects a single decimal number, but was given two. (`2 3`).

You should either put the input numbers on separate lines, or fix your program to split the numbers before passing them to `parseDouble`.

Comment: I am curious as to why you focused on the third line of the exception instead of the first, which has the `parseDouble` that the OP is actually calling directly.

Comment: I am highlighting the parseDouble line to show the part that's failing. The first line of the stack-trace just shows the exception, and not the method that's called from the main program. It seemed that the OP thought that the error was in BufferedReader according to the question title.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving `2 3`

try giving

```
2
3
```